# How to deal with more than three PHP GET Variables to Select data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a PHP page called `get.php` that has access to MySQL Database.
I use one table called: `MyTable`

In the table I have more than on row.
Every info has an `id` that I use to get the other info based on it:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE `id`='" . $_GET["var1"]'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
.
.
.
```

So when I go to:

```
localhost/bb/t2/get.php?var1=1
```

I get the other info like Name of the info by fetching the rows.

**BUT** I want to deal with more than one variable:

```
localhost/bb/t2/get.php?var1=1&var2=2&var4=4&...
```

So I can get the info of every `id` and not one only.

I want to handle any number of variables and get it's data.

Thank you!

Comment: Build the query dynamically and use parameterized queries, open to SQL injections as is...or are all the `GET` parameters `id`s?

Comment: Thank you for reply but the method didn't work :/

Comment: What method? Update the question to your code.

Comment: You must not assemble your queries like this, because it exposes you to a kind of security breach called *SQL injection*. To circumvent this, use PHP's [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and set your values as parameters on the query, or use a DBAL (database abstraction layer) such as Doctrine (there are many good other ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it would be easier to use an array for specifying multiple ids in the URL:

```
http://localhost/bb/t2/get.php?var[]=1&var[]=2&var[]=4&...
```

This way, in your PHP code `$_GET['var']` will be an array and will contain all values specified in the URL.

Next, you have to make sure all array items (the ids) are numeric. There are many solutions for this, for example skipping non-numeric values:

```
// make sure parameters are OK
if (is_array($_GET['var'])) {
    // eliminate non-numeric values
    $ids = array_filter($_GET['var'], function($item) {
        return is_numeric($item);
    });
}
else {
    // invalid arguments; throw exception or do something else
}
```

Finally, you have to use WHERE IN in your query (and verify of course if there are actually some values in the $ids array before executing the SQL query):

```
if (!empty($ids)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE `id` IN (" . implode(",", $ids) . ")";
}
else {
    //TODO: no numeric ids specified, do something else...
}
```

Comment: ... and NOT just add user data directly to a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you want to use the variables to determine what fields you are selecting, or to use them to determine what id's are being searched for. Either way it sounds like you just want to be able to pass any number of queries in the urls query string to get what you are looking for.

PHP can actually parse arrays from the query string if composed properly.

Here is an example.

```
http://localhost/index.php?query1[]=var1&query1[]=var2&query1[]=var3
```

Note the `[]` after each query name. This is what the contents of $_GET would be in PHP.

```
$_GET = [
    "query1" => [
            "var1",
            "var2",
            "var3"
        ]
];
```

Now you can just get whatever fields or id's from the database that are listed in the array.